# Selecting only the rows in one data frame that also have rows in a smaller, second date frame

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I have one data set called 'timp_serum' with a first column like this:

```
Pat_ID
4
6
8
9
11
35
45
67
...
```

And another, called 'dat', like this:

```
patid
6
8
9
11
35
67
...
```

I want to take the from the first data frame only those rows that are found in the second data frame.

I am using dplyr, and I tried making a vector of the patid column from dat and writing the code

```
timp_serum_reduced <- select(timp_serum, Pat_ID == (patid.vector))
```

and got this error:

```
Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  Pat_ID == (patid.vector)
```

I also tried:

```
timp_serum_reduced <- select(timp_serum, Pat_ID -one_of (patid.vector))
```

Comment: do you want to use `merge()` ?

Comment: Try something like `timp_serum[timp_serum$Pat_ID %in% dat$patid]`

Comment: This is very easy with r basic functions too.

Comment: Dplyrish for this is something like `semi_join(DF1,DF2)`. Read `?semi_join` to see docs for the family of dplyr mergers.

Comment: I guess I would be better off merging, using only those rows where the patient id numbers match. That would save a step. I'm going to make a few tries before I get frustrated  and come back here for advice.

Comment: It worked using 'filter' as below. I didn't try the solution given by DatamineR, but I am going to try it next time.

Answer (score 0):

It's 'filter', not 'select' function you should use. If you want to use dplyr, of course.

```
timp_serum_reduced <- filter(timp_serum, Pat_ID %in% dat$patid)
```

PS. I'm not able to comment yet, so I have to write it as an answer.